Como agregar un Array dentro de otro hasta 4 subniveles usando mongodb y nodejs
Estoy intentando crear un array dentro de otro dinamicamente hasta un 3er nivel, en el primer nivel use $push pero ya para el segundo no me funciono
{
    _id: ObjectId('6621d633b5b8ec34fa9e9123'),
    label: 'Movimiento Vehicular IDAAN',
    folders: [
      {
        name: 'Datos Generales ',
        fields: [],
        _id: ObjectId('6621ea3a15daf6369ba5cb86')
      },
      {
        name: 'Datos de Vehículo y Conductor',
        fields: [],
        _id: ObjectId('6621ea8415daf6369ba5cb89')
      }
    ],
    createdAt: ISODate('2024-04-19T02:25:55.522Z'),
    updatedAt: ISODate('2024-04-23T13:33:24.899Z')
  }

Logre agregar 2 objetos dentro del array folders, pero cuando intento con fields no lo logro.
export const newfieldwithfolder = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const { name, label, order, type, requ, par } = req.body;
    const query = { _id: req.params.id };
    const newfields = new Fields({
      name,
      label,
      order,
      type,
      requ,
      par,
    }); 
    const newfield = { $push: { fields: newfields } };
    const result = await Template.updateOne(query, newfield);
    console.log(result)
    res.status(201).json({ message: "Fields have been added successfully!" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: "Something went Wrong!" });
  }
};

Este es el codigo del back donde newfields es el objeto que intento agregar dentro del array fields. Agradeco su ayuda ya que soy nuevo usando mongodb
La estructura final que busco es anadir dos o mas objetos dentro del array fields
_id: ObjectId('6621d633b5b8ec34fa9e9123'),
label: 'Movimiento Vehicular IDAAN',
folders: [
  {
    name: 'Datos Generales ',
    fields: [
      {     
        name: 'Dia',
        label: 'Dia',
        order: 11,
        type: 'number',
        requ: true,
        par: 'Datos Generales',
        _id: ObjectId('6627d08ce19e75eb0a46197c')
      },

        name: 'Fecha',
        label: 'Fecha',
        order: 12,
        type: 'date',
        requ: true,
        par: 'Datos Generales',
        _id: ObjectId('6627d2178f2ef65652cce7de')
      }


    ],
    _id: ObjectId('6621ea3a15daf6369ba5cb86')
  },
  {
    name: 'Datos de Vehículo y Conductor',
    fields: [],
    _id: ObjectId('6621ea8415daf6369ba5cb89')
  }
],
createdAt: ISODate('2024-04-19T02:25:55.522Z'),
updatedAt: ISODate('2024-04-23T13:33:24.899Z')

}

Tienes un ejemplo de la estructura final que pretendes tener con un ejemplo de los datos

Saludos jachguate. La estructura final es esta donde busco anadir dos objetos dentro del array fields.
